# How to overload and call a method in a derived class which was previously defined in its base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, derived-class, base-class

This is the base class:

```
template <class T>
class DataLogger
{
        // ...
    public:
        void AddData(T Data);
        // ...
}
```

And this is the derived class:

```
#include "DataLogger.h"
#include <utility>

class Plotter : public DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>
{
        // ...
    public:
        void AddData(long double x, long double y);
        // ...
}

// This method is supposed to wrap the original AddData() method
// which was defined in the base class
void Plotter::AddData(long double x, long double y)
{
    AddData(std::make_pair(x, y));  // LINE #29
}
```

The given error is:

> LINE 29: IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::pair" to "long double" exists
>
> LINE 29: IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call

Apparently, the problem is that I can not access to the method in base class from derived class, even though it is defined public.

How do I make this code work?

(My IDE is Visual Studio 2010.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `AddData` from the base is hidden by the `AddData` from derived class. Either explicitly qualify the call `DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>::AddData(...)` or bring it to scope with `using DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>::AddData;`

Comment: "DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>::AddData(...)" this one worked. But I didn't understand the mechanism behind it. AddData() in the base class is not static. How can we call it in this format?

Comment: You tell the compiler where the method is from. The shorter version is to say __::AddData(..)__ -- use the previous parent class where AddData was declared.

Comment: @Rapheal B.: When I use the short version "::AddData()", compiler gives this error: "Error C2039: 'AddData' : is not a member of '`global namespace''".

Answer (score 2):

Your `AddData` in derived class hides the function `AddData` in the base class, so all you need to do is, unhide the latter using `using` directive:

```
class Plotter : public DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>
{

public:
   //unhiding : bringing base class function into scope!
   using DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>::AddData;

};
```

Read **Item 33: Avoid hiding inherited names** from [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call the *super* class method write `::AddData(x, y);`. The new `Plotter::AddData` method makes `DataLogger::AddData` *invisible*.

Comment: *supper* class is making me hungry ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not "that I can not access to the method in base class from derived class, even though it is defined public".

The problem is that Plotter::AddData is trying to call itself (with a pair) instead of the AddData in the base class.

You can make the call explicit by writing

```
void Plotter::AddData(long double x, long double y)
{
    DataLogger<std::pair<long double, long double>>::AddData(std::make_pair(x, y));
}
```